# How browser extensions change website without editing HTML?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For example, Skype plugin for Chrome highlights phone numbers on websites and allows to make calls. Website source codes appear to be not modified. Any ideas how does it do it?

Comment: They dynamically update the HTML. You will see it if you look at [dev tools' element panel](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#dom-and-styles).

Comment: Thanks, @JuanMendes , I see those changes now. Where can I read more about the implementation of such approach?

Comment: google for chrome extension content script in the official docs